# "Element not found in the cache ..." although the same command code works when run through IRB

Tags: ruby, exception, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a script where on entering input and hitting enter, new field for text input open ups.
When the script is run, the cursor goes into this newly opened field, but it does not enter input as expected. I have specified explicit timeout and the script waits for that particular time but still fails throwing: -

```
"Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up"


#Enter no. of nights
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"1",:return

#Enter no. of rooms
browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2",:return
```

I have tried both implicit and explicit waits but that doesn't help either.

Strangely, if I execute the steps manually in ruby shell, everything works perfectly fine!

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks!
Abhishek

Comment: If you would like people to be able to help you, you need to provide some code to show what you are trying to do, otherwise there is no way people can help.

Comment: @MikeH-R added the code; No. of rooms text input field opens once the user enters value in #No. of nights and hits enter (function triggers no. of rooms display)